# is it possible to get mempool transactions as hex using bitcoin-core?

Tags: transactions, mempool

`getrawmempool` returns only TXID (verbose off), what I'm doing is calling `getrawtransaction` for each transaction ID to get a transaction hex.

Bitcoin core doesn't support batch requests and each RPC call takes 0.06 sec, for ~ 5000 transactions, it takes 5 min which is so expensive. 
can I get mempool transactions as hex instantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bitcoin core doesn't support batch requests

Yes it does. Bitcoin Core uses the follows the [JSON-RPC Specification for batching requests](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#batch). Just use that with a custom client of your choice to interact with the RPC server to get that information. [python-bitcoinrpc](https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc) makes this easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need Bitcoin Core and RPC calls for this task?

May be you need some tool for sniffing bitcoin network for all transactions. Have a look to this: https://github.com/sebicas/bitcoin-sniffer

This tool is very old. I am not sure that it works today. Take the main idea.

---

Another solution is implementing your own RPC-command. Something like "dumpwholemempool". I think it is not too difficult.